# Loop and change pixel values in Mat OpenCV Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I am now building a project based on the sample color blob tracking method. I used bounding rectangles around the contours to indicate the blobs. Now I want to improve this algorithm by using an error correction method. What I do now is simply summing up the pixels in the rect region using elemsum method and calculate the average intensity and set it as the new blob detection parameter in each frame. However, the problem is that it is not accurate since those pixels outside the contour but inside the bounding rect will be counted as well. And the result is poor.

In order to solve the problem, I used another a straightforward way to loop through each pixel in the rectangle region (which is a submat), and set all pixel values out of range to the desired (or previous) hsv scalar. Then sum up all the pixels again and calculate the average intensity. This would much more accurate and easily solves the problem. The problem is that the program runs too slow on the phone (with around 1 frame per sec), though the result is accurate.

I found some sources online on how to do it in c++ using mat.forEach. I do not want to do the ndk thing and I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it in Java (Android).

**UPDATE:
It turned out I can solve the problem by simply reducing the sampling rate. Instead of calculating the average intensity of all pixels, just a few number of them would do the job. My code:**

```
for (int i=0; i< bounding_rect_hsv.rows();i+=10){
                for (int j=0; j<bounding_rect_hsv.cols();j+=10){
                    double[] data = bounding_rect_hsv.get(i, j);
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                        if (data[k] > new_hsvColor.val[k] + 30 || data[k] < new_hsvColor.val[k] - 30) {
                            data[k] = new_hsvColor.val[k];
                        }
                    }
                    bounding_rect_hsv.put(i, j, data); //Puts element back into matrix
                }
            }
```

My source code:

```
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

// draw enclosing rectangle (all same color, but you could use variable i to make them unique)
Imgproc.rectangle(original_frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);

//Todo: use the bounding rectangular to calculate average intensity (turn the pixels out of the contour to new_hsvColor)
//Just change the boundary values would be enough
bounding_rect_rgb = original_frame.submat(rect);
Imgproc.cvtColor(bounding_rect_rgb, bounding_rect_hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

//Todo: change the logic so that pixels outside the contour will be changed to new_hsvColor

for (int i=0; i< bounding_rect_hsv.rows();i++){
    for (int j=0; j<bounding_rect_hsv.cols();j++){
        double[] data = bounding_rect_hsv.get(i, j);
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        if (data[k] > new_hsvColor.val[k] + 30 || data[k] < new_hsvColor.val[k] - 30)
        data[k] = new_hsvColor.val[k];
        }
        bounding_rect_hsv.put(i, j, data); //Puts element back into matrix
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the *mean* value of pixels inside a contour you can simply:

1. Create a mask, using [drawContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#drawcontours) with parameter `CV_FILLED` and color `Scalar(255)` on a black (`Scalar(0)`) initialized `CV_8UC1` image with same size as the original image.
2. Use [mean](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) to compute the mean of pixels under the mask.

---

You also don't need to convert to HSV every region (`Rect`), but you can convert the whole image once, and then access the desired region directly on the HSV image.

---

In the general case you want to sum the pixel values of a lot of rectangular regions, you may prefer to compute the [integral](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral) image and compute the sum as the difference of values at bottom-right and top-left rectangle positions.